# Copy Cell Color and Send in EMAIL Body

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Column G has been set with conditional formatting.If less than 0.95, no highlight; if between 0.95 and 1.0, highlighted in green; if over 1.0, highlighted in red.
[Table in sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cmKo.png)

Can you please help capture the color in the sheet and copy to HTML email body? Many thanks.

Please find the code as below.

```js
      
 function last_row(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet 1");
  var data = ss.getRange(1,1,100).getValues();
  var lrow = 0;
  for (i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    if(row[0] != ""){
    lrow++;
    }
   }

function match(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Match');
  var match = ss.getRange(1,1,19,3).getValues();

function email_to_mgmt(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sheet 1');
  var lastrow = last_row();
  var data = ss.getRange(1,1,lastrow,9).getValues();
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Match');
  var match = s.getRange(1,1,19,3).getValues();

  var headers = ss.getRange("A1:H1").getValues();
  var pgm_name = headers[0][0];
  var bug_id = headers[0][1];
  var rb_bug_reporter = headers[0][2];
  var rb_bug_yq = headers[0][3];
  var rb_approved_amount = headers[0][4];
  var total_po_spend = headers[0][5];
  var rb_unilization = headers[0][6];
  var scpm_cms = headers[0][7];

  var tableRange = ss.getRange(2,1,lastrow-1,8)
  var tableRangeValues = tableRange.getDisplayValues();
  var colors = tableRange.getBackgrounds().map(([a]) =>a);


  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email");
  htmlTemplate.pgm_name = pgm_name;
  htmlTemplate.bug_id = bug_id;
  htmlTemplate.rb_bug_reporter = rb_bug_reporter;
  htmlTemplate.rb_bug_yq = rb_bug_yq;
  htmlTemplate.rb_approved_amount = rb_approved_amount;
  htmlTemplate.total_po_spend = total_po_spend;
  htmlTemplate.rb_unilization = rb_unilization;
  htmlTemplate.scpm_cms = scpm_cms;
  

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1 style="color:#3368FF">Headerxxx</h1>
       <div style= font-size:14x>The following....</div>
    </div>
  <div></div>
  <table style="border-collapse:collapse;"border = 2 cellpadding = 6;>
    <thead>
      <tr style= "background-color:#00ffff;font-weight:bold;white-space:nowrap;text-align:center;">
        <th><?= pgm_name ?></th><th><?= bug_id ?></th><th><?= rb_bug_reporter ?></th><th><?= rb_bug_yq ?></th><th><?= rb_approved_amount ?></th><th><?= total_po_spend ?></th><th><?= rb_unilization ?></th><th><?= scpm_cms ?></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <? tableRangeValues.forEach((r,i)=>{ ?>
      <tr style="background-color: <?= colors[i]?>">
        <td> <?= r[0] ?> </td>
        <td> <?= r[1] ?> </td>
        <td> <?= r[2] ?> </td>
        <td> <?= r[3] ?> </td>
        <td> <?= r[4] ?> </td>
        <td> <?= r[5] ?> </td>
        <td> <?= r[6] ?> </td>
        <td> <?= r[7] ?> </td>
      </tr>  
      <?})?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

htmlTemplate.colors = colors;

```
  htmlTemplate.tableRange = tableRange;
  htmlTemplate.tableRangeValues = tableRangeValues;

  var htmlForEmail = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();

  var week = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Match").getRange(1,6).getValue();

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "xxx@gmail.com",
    subject:xxx,
    htmlBody: htmlForEmail});
}
```

Comment: This works perfect and much simpler. You are great. I've been trying by myself for a while. I'm more than happy when the modified script finally solved my problem. Really appreciate. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to set the background color of the column "G" in the HTML data. The color information is from `sheet 1` sheet in the Spreadsheet.

In this case, how about the following modified script?

### Modified script:

#### Google Apps Script side:

```js
function email_to_mgmt() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet 1");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:H" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var [[pgm_name, bug_id, rb_bug_reporter, rb_bug_yq, rb_approved_amount, total_po_spend, rb_unilization, scpm_cms], ...tableRangeValues] = range.getDisplayValues();
  var [, ...colors] = range.getBackgrounds().map(e => e[6]);
  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email");
  var obj = {pgm_name, bug_id, rb_bug_reporter, rb_bug_yq, rb_approved_amount, total_po_spend, rb_unilization, scpm_cms, tableRangeValues, colors};
  htmlTemplate.obj = obj;
  var htmlForEmail = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
  MailApp.sendEmail({ to: "xxx@gmail.com", subject: xxx, htmlBody: htmlForEmail });
}
```

- I thought that the header row and the value rows can be retrieved by one call.
- I thought that when an object is used for sending to HTML template, the script might be simpler.

#### HTML side:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1 style="color:#3368FF">Headerxxx</h1>
       <div style= font-size:14x>The following....</div>
    </div>
  <div></div>
  <table style="border-collapse:collapse;"border = 2 cellpadding = 6;>
    <thead>
      <tr style= "background-color:#00ffff;font-weight:bold;white-space:nowrap;text-align:center;">
        <th><?= obj.pgm_name ?></th><th><?= obj.bug_id ?></th><th><?= obj.rb_bug_reporter ?></th><th><?= obj.rb_bug_yq ?></th><th><?= obj.rb_approved_amount ?></th><th><?= obj.total_po_spend ?></th><th><?= obj.rb_unilization ?></th><th><?= obj.scpm_cms ?></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <? obj.tableRangeValues.forEach((r,i)=>{ ?>
      <tr>
        <td> <?= r[0] ?> </td>
        <td> <?= r[1] ?> </td>
        <td> <?= r[2] ?> </td>
        <td> <?= r[3] ?> </td>
        <td> <?= r[4] ?> </td>
        <td> <?= r[5] ?> </td>
        <td style="background-color: <?= obj.colors[i]?>"> <?= r[6] ?> </td>
        <td> <?= r[7] ?> </td>
      </tr>  
      <?})?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

- When you want to change the background color of cell of column "G", please add the style to the tag `td`.

### References:

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)